# Famo.us opacity : 0 surface optimization

Tags: performance, optimization, view, opacity, famo.us

I have one question about performance thing.

I have some animated Views, that have internally many layers (8 layers), but only 4 are visible at once, other have opacity of 0.

I am just wondering, if the surface has opacity of 0, is it rendered or is it culled down?

And if it is rendered, where/how do I disable it (mark non-renderable) with if-check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements with opacity 0 don't render, and in famous, surfaces use perspective-3d which usually results in the browser compositing the contents as a gpu texture of sorts. This results in a huge performance increase.

Opacity 0 elements will still receive events however, which makes it different from, say, visibility hidden, which will ignore all events.

Comment: Ok, big thanks! So I can just set elements with opacity 0 and forget about them :).

Comment: For events.. I just use invisible ContainerSurface @ top of everything, because I had problems with multiple surfaces anyway (icons, text, etc)